# How to create a download button/link in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, download

Is there a way to create a download button on java swing? I tried searching the internet for an answer but I only got links on how to create a download link on jsp/servlet

Comment: Applets are not really meant to be a delivery system for files, it sort of renders their security measures useless.

Comment: thank you for your reply. not pertaining to applets though. I am talking about a desktop application using java swing.

Comment: You would need to create a regular java button(JButton), that when clicked calls a function which does the download.

Comment: Apologies for my applet assumptions. See others comments and answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a JButton whose ActionListeners ActionPerformed function performs the file download.

Here is a stackoverflow link on how to download files from a url with Java

[How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Here is an example, not tested

```
...
JButton jb = new JButton('Download Button');
jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Download file
        URL url = new URL('www.example.com/example_file.jpg');
        File f = new File('...');
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, f);
    }
});
...
```